# Why are the heading size tags not deprecated in HTML5?

Tags: css, html

It seems to me that specifying the "importance" (read "size") of an element in the HTML violates the principle of separation of concerns that HTML5 espouses so much.  If the designers of HTML5 deprecated tags like `<big>` and `<strike>` (see this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_deprecated_tags.htm) for a list of other such elements) because their behavior can and should be replicated in CSS, why wasn't the same done to the heading size tags (`<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc...)?  Could these tags not have all been merged into one `<h>` tag, and then have CSS classes added to them to size them properly (eg `<h1 class="big-header">`)?

It seems highly arbitrary that the designers of HTML5 would include only six (see this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp)) `<h>` tags, all to be interpreted and displayed slightly differently.  How was the number six determined?  Why would they not develop one tag and leave it up to the developer to style it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<h1>`, `<h2>` ... `<h6>` are semantically important; they have a meaning besides the default styles. For the same reason `<nav>`, `<aside>`, `<article>`, `<footer>`, etc. were added in HTML5.

Comment: So how did they decide that headings are only semantically different six levels deep?

Comment: How often in any document do you need more than six levels? You're not limited to one instance of any heading tag.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the spec:

> Because HTML conveys meaning, rather than presentation, the same page can also be used by a small browser on a mobile phone, without any change to the page. Instead of headings being in large letters as on the desktop, for example, the browser on the mobile phone might use the same size text for the whole the page, but with the headings in bold.

It seems as if maybe they wanted to allow responsiveness to be built into the standard, and that may be part of the reason.

[Link to the quoted passage](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#semantics-0)

If they left it to the developer to supply all CSS for headings, why use headings at all, aside from semantic meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the number in h are not related with size, are related with content deep, titles and sub titles so h1 represent the main title, h2 represents second level subtitles, h3 3rd level of subtitles and so on.

Comment: But why wouldn't they have made a `<heading>` tag and a `<subtitle>` tag to do this?  It would be trivial to differentiate second and third level subtitles with CSS classes.

Comment: @macsj200 - They aren't heading _size_ tags — they are heading _level_ tags. They provide a semantic meaning indicating the document has a hierarchical structure, in a way that applying classes to `<heading>` can't.